# How can a tensor be flipped in Theano?

Tags: theano

Given a tensor `v = t.vector()`, how can I flip it?
For instance, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` flipped is `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do `v[::-1].eval()`, or just `v[::-1]` in the middle of your computational graph.

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano import tensor as T

X_values = np.arange(10).astype(theano.config.floatX)
X = T.shared(X_values, 'X')
print(X.eval())
print(X[::-1].eval())
```

See the section on indexing [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I know I'm late to the party here, but I've just started playing with Theano, and thought I'd throw in this variation, since I don't think shared values were necessary:

```
 from theano import tensor as T
 from theano import function as Tfunc

 z = T.vector()
 f = Tfunc([z],z[::-1])
```

This gives:

```
 >>> f([1,3,5,7,9])
 array([ 9.,  7.,  5.,  3.,  1.])
```